# How do I change a CCSprite's Dimensions after changing texture?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a piece of code in my iOS project that swaps the texture of a CCSprite via setTexture, like so:

```
[sprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"Circle.png"]];
```

However, the dimensions of the CCSprite's texture before and after the swap are different, and as a result, the Circle.png texture is getting cropped; stuck at the size of original texture (as the circle is larger).

How can I adjust the size after swapping the Texture?

([Related, but not helpful in solving this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252330/ios-and-cocos2d-changing-ccsprites-image-and-new-dimensions-fail))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
CCTexture2D* texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"Circle.png"];

    if (texture)
    {
                // Get the size of the new texture:
        CGSize size = [texture contentSize];

        [sprite setTexture:texture];
                // use the size of the new texture:
        [sprite setTextureRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width,size.height)];
     }
```

Comment: I had to add a little more code to get the proper lengths to get this working, so I've added it as a suggested edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can just recreate sprite with spriteWithFile constructor. the dimensions will be set automatically

Comment: Doing this runs into issues with memory management, bad access, and zombies. Could you elaborate with a little more information on how you'd do memory management along with this?

Comment: I don't see any problem with memory here. Just remove the first sprite from parent, create the new one with new file, and add it to the needed parent.